# program for finding ones compliment of a binary number.im getting wrong o/p ,is my logic wrong?

Tags: c

```
int onec(int bin)
{
    int one_compliment=0;
    for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
    {
        one_compliment+=(bin%10==1)?0*pow(10,i):1*pow(10,i);
        bin=bin/10;
    }
    return one_compliment;
}
```

this is a function on my program to find ones compliment

Comment: The `~` operator is the one's complement operator in C.

Comment: When you have a program that produces "wrong output", it's helpful to give an example of the _input_, show the actual output, and show what you expect the output to be.

Comment: Include a simple main function with a single statement like `printf("%d\n", onec(<number>));` where <number> is an actual number. Then tell us what it prints and what you expect it to print instead.

Comment: It's pointless to use floating point math functions, multiplication and division for working at bit level.

Comment: Also what does this code have to do with one's complement? It seems you except some manner of BCD weird input like `int bin = 11101010;` and then you translate that decimal goo to actual binary. Without caring about one's complement because you ignore the MSB special case for signed numbers. So you need to clarify what this code should actually do, because it isn't doing anything related to one's complement, then explain expected input & output.